# Chrome crash when I send a print request to another tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a link with a simple javascript code:

```
<a href="javascript: w=window.open('https://mywebsite.com/print/f47aea8bdcbd1179a1f3d91e6afeeb259488f2d1'); w.print();" class="btn btn-primary btn">
      <i class="icon-print"></i>
<span class="hidden-xs">Print</span>
```

It opens the new tab and the tab I was broke;

Devtools disconnect and I can't see what's going on.

Comment: What happens when you manually open the link in a new tab?

Comment: The tab i need to print send print dialog normaly. But the page that I came from broke.

Comment: Well. Apparently, the reference "w.print()" when it is comming from another tab realy send the print event. but broken the page. I set the onload event to the page i need to open and print in a function and it's works.